# Ubuntu 14.04 UWF for iptables

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, redhat, systemd

Can I still use the init.d iptables stop?

It seems that init.d is replaced by systemd. Is that correct?

The iptables is part of the kernel right and not a service. On redhat based systems it is a service why?

I am used to

```
int.d/service iptables stop
```

Can I get it back?

Answer (score 1):

Actually. i found out the answer

in ubuntu systemd is not used by ubuntu at the moment ( at least not yet) you can install and use systemd if you want to,

right now ubuntu now uses UFW ( iptables is not removed) UFW enables users to use iptables in a better way, easy to add rules. etc

The  init.d is still there with symbolic links to upstart to eg : service apache2 restart would work as per normal

..

if there is any mistakes in my answer, someone please feel free to correct me

init.d( SysV) /upstart / systemd

here is a page that provides more details

https://wiki.debian.org/Debate/initsystem/upstart